# Apache SSL invalid certificate chain with "https://www"

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

My site has a ssl certificate installed for a virtual host in my apache setup. It redirects `http` to `https` and https://sitename.com works  but for some reason when the user explicitly types the `www`, "https://www.sitename.com", I get an invalid certificate error.

`http://www.sitename.com` works but once you use https, it all breaks.

This is part of my apache configuration for the virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sitename.com
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ https://sitename.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName catch-all.sitename.com
ServerAlias *.sitename.com
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ https://sitename.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName sitename.com
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000
SSLProxyEngine on
```

Comment: Look at the subject alternative name(s) on the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httpd doesn't know what the hostname in the host header is until the decryption process takes place, so if the original request doesn't match the hostname in the certificate, you will get an error.

If you want to have both domains work with https, you will need either:

1. 2 x ip addresses with 2 individual certs, with each one attached to an ip address
2. A wildcard certificate that works with both domains

A wildcard is the best option, but I'm guessing you didn't buy one of these, and that you have a cert that is specific to "sitename.com"

Comment: Or, Option 3: SNI

Comment: Still going to require another cert, so may as well just get the wildcard.

Comment: Is there a way to just redirect `https://www` requests to `https://` only? Or is does it not know the hostname at that point?

Comment: You'ld still need a certificate valid for both names, or 2 IPs.

Comment: No, you can't do that. As per answer, the only hostname the server knows upon the initial request is the hostname requested in the GET. It can't act upon anything in the host headers until after decryption has taken place.